# append value to form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to get values from form and append it to a form and then pass that value as parameter

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#buttonClick').on('click', 'button',function firstCall(){

var form = new FormData();
form.append("name", "test");
form.append("phone", "2245201905");
form.append("url", "this_url");
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "url_path",
  "method": "POST",
  "processData": false,
  "contentType": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "data": form
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});});
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" id="formSample">
 <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Fullname">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
      <label for="phone">phone</label>
      <input type="number" name="phone" placeholder="number">
 </div>
 <div id="buttonClick">
 <button >Submit</button></div>
```

In my script I have hardcoded the value of name, phone and url and it is working by I am not able to append the value from form..
so I am looking for

```
form.append("name", "(document.getElementById('name').value");
```

Also on button click I am not able to pass data as I have placed alert but I dont my code enter function

NOTE: I haven't worked on url part yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a FormData with valued from the actual HTML you can pass that form to form data as parameter

```
<form id="myForm">
   <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Fullname">
   <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
</form>
<script>
var myform = document.getElementById('myForm');
var form = new FormData(myform);
// form will have name and phone
form.append("url", window.location.href);

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
   if (response.success) {
      // Only do something if the response data has success key.
   }
});});
</script>
```

Comment: yep thanks.. this worked..

I also have another doubt when I am making API response I want to display this for only when response is true.. any guidance?

Comment: @raulxbox No need to thanks me. Just upvote and accept please :D

Comment: I did but they say you can upvote answer after 2 minutes.. I will do that. also how do I pass current page url to form

Comment: current page url = window.location.href

Comment: thanks again
I only want to display this form when response = true so I know I can display none and then display block but is that a good practice?

Comment: Yes, you can show hide the form as much as you want

Comment: `var form = FormData(myform);` has to be `var form = new FormData(myform);` right?

Answer (score 2):

```
form.append("name", "(document.getElementById('name').value");
```

you are appending a string here. Just remove the "

```
form.append("name", document.getElementById('name').value);
```

Also you may want to take a closer look at anonymous [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) and [data types](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp) in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do it much simpler by getting only the whole form and pass it to [`FormData` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData). You should set name for your inputs though

```js
function firstCall(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var htmlForm = document.getElementById('formSample');
      var form = new FormData(htmlForm);
      form.append("url", "this_url");
      
      // perform the ajax request
      form.forEach((e, i) => { console.log(i, e); });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // You can use named function if you need to reuse it elsewhere
    $('#buttonClick').on('click', 'button', firstCall);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="formSample">
 <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Fullname">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
      <label for="phone">phone</label>
      <input type="number" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="number">
 </div>
 <div id="buttonClick">
 <button >Submit</button></div>
```

Comment: yeah this is really simpler.. But where are you making ajax call? instead of console.log  right?

Comment: You can keep the part you did

Comment: what do you mean by this // Don't use named function here

Comment: [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler) third argument is a callback, in your case you can use an anonymous function instead of a named one (you didn't need to give it firstCall as name)

Comment: ok but I do have anothor API Call so I guess I have to use a function name here